# chmod で パーミッション の変更が出来ない

Tags: windows, ssh, git-bash

GitHubを利用するために以下ページを参考に、`.ssh` フォルダのパーミッションを変更したいのですが、変更できずに困っています。

[今日からはじめるGitHub - Gitのインストールと準備](https://employment.en-japan.com/engineerhub/entry/2017/01/31/110000#Git%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A8%E6%BA%96%E5%82%99)

> 生成された秘密鍵のパーミッションを `600` に変更します。
>
> ```
> $ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
> ```
>
> 「`-rw-------`」になっていれば正しいパーミッションに変更できています。

ここで同様の操作を行ってもパーミッションが変更されません。
`-c` オプションを使用して確認したところ、変更できている旨が表示されますが、
実際には変更できていないという状態です。

解決方法を教えていただきたく投稿させていただきます。
よろしくお願いいたします。

なお、実行環境は Windows 10 になります。

Comment: ファイルオーナーと同一アカウントでコマンドは打ってる状態ですか？`sudo`打っても駄目？

Comment: コマンド入力はファイルオーナーです。

Comment: sudo は使用できない旨が表示されます

Answer (score 4, accepted):

もしWindowsの**git bash**を使用している場合、NTFS/FAT32等のファイルシステム上では`chmod`でアクセス権を変更することはできません。
(一見`chmod -c`で変更されたように表示されるのは確かに紛らわしいですね)

また、参考にされたページの手順で実行している「秘密鍵のパーミッション変更」ですが、こちらはシステム上の他のユーザから不用意にファイルを参照されないようにするためのものです。
Windowsで`chmod`は実行できないと書きましたが、元々Windowsでは他のユーザアカウントのデータは(管理者権限が無い限り)見えないようアクセス制御されていますので、「秘密鍵のパーミッション変更」は実行しないままで大丈夫です。

Comment: なるほど！大変勉強になりました。ありがとうございました！

Comment: 補足すると、Windows以外(？)で秘密鍵のパーミッションを`600`にするのが必須なのは、[公開鍵認証時にエラーではじかれる](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22UNPROTECTED+PRIVATE+KEY+FILE%22)からですね。

Comment: @yukihane 「エラーで弾かれるから」パーミッションを変更するのではなく、「適切なパーミッション(`600`)でない場合にエラーで弾かれる」ですよね？目的と手段を混同されている気がします。