# Windows 7 から ssh が使いたい

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh, mingw

普段大学の Linux マシンでプログラムしてるのですが
土日にうちで勉強したくて Windows 7 でコマンドラインを使える環境を作りたいと思ってます

まず SSH をできるようにしたいんですが
[Windows7にmingw-getでMSYSのsshとrsyncをインストールする](http://heroween.hateblo.jp/entry/2014/06/06/203440)

こちらを参考にして MSYS と MinGW をいれて

```
mingw-get install msys-openssl msys-openssh msys-rsync
```

を行ったところ成功したみたいなんですが
どこにインストールされたかわからず、ssh うってみてもコマンドが見つかりません

あきらめて
[コマンドプロンプトからSSH接続したい](https://usado.jp/spdsk/2018/06/01/post-3815/)

こちらの方法を試してみて
OpenSSH-Win64.zip を/user/local/ 以下に回答して

```
/user/local/OpenSSH-Win64/ssh test
```

とコマンドうってみたんですが

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

というメッセージがでます

SSH に限らず Windows 7 環境でターミナルやシェル一式を整えるようなまとめサイトがあったら教えていただきたいです

Virtual Box をいれるのも考えたんですが
うちのPCがあまりスペックがよくなくて
ゲームとかするときにしょっちゅうメモリぎりぎりになるので
毎回落として起動しなおしになるのも面倒なので

できればネイティブで動くシェルとターミナルにしたいです
（どうしても無理なら VirtualBox にチェレンジしようと思ってます）

#### 環境

Windows 7 64bit MSYS MinGW

#### 追記

２つ目の方法でインストールしいた exe は
コマンドプロンプトで実行すると動くみたいなんですが

```
ssh user@host -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

を実行すると キーのパーミションがあきすぎてるっていうエラーで動きません

```
chmod go-rwx ~/.ssh/*
```

を実行してもエラーも何も出ないんですが
`ls -l` で確認すると go のパーミションがついたままで消すことができません

余計なお世話すぎるんですがパーミッション無視して動かすようなオプションってないでしょうか…

Windows 7 でコマンドラインから SSH するだけでもこんな大変なんですね…
はやくも心が折れそうです

Comment: Windows 10やmsys2の場合はできる方法が異なってきますので、Windows 7を明記し、msys2のタグは外しています。もし、Windows 10へアップグレードすることも含めての回答が欲しい場合は、質問に明記をお願いします。

Comment: 「chmod go-rwx ~/.ssh/* を実行しても go のパーミションを消すことができないです」の部分ですが、何らかのエラーメッセージが表示されたのでしょうか？

Comment: 「Windows上でLinuxのコマンド環境を作る」と「sshでLinuxに接続する環境を作る」では意味合いが異なります。真の目的が後者であるなら、TeraTerm等のアプリでssh接続してしまえば "Windows上でコマンドラインを使える" にこだわる必要が無くなります。

Comment: 「Windows上でLinuxのコマンド環境を作る」が目的です。とりあえず bashrc とか .emacs とかをもってこようとしてただけで winscp を使えば先にすすめはするんですが後々のために ssh で大学の環境に入れるようにもしたいです

Comment: > chmod 何らかのエラーメッセージが表示されたのでしょうか？ 　何も表示されません　本文に追記しました

Comment: おそらく、今 @chico さんの PC にはたくさんの ssh がインストールされていると思います。症状を確認する時には、意図した ssh が実行されているか確認した方がよいと思いますよ。

Comment: こちらの質問も関連しているかも?: [chmod で パーミッション の変更が出来ない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/44239/2808)

Comment: みてみたんですが「「秘密鍵のパーミッション変更」は実行しないままで大丈夫です」とあるんですが実際それでエラーで動かないので解決法がよくわからないです。言ってることはわかるのでパーミション無視するようなオプションがあればいいんですが

Comment: 回答にも記載しましたが、Win32-OpenSSHは[Git for Windows付属のもの](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/44239/2808)と異なりパーミッションをちゃんと見ているようでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

結局どの方法も windows 環境で .ssh 以下のファイルのパーミション閉じる方法がわからなかったので VirtualBox を入れました
せっかく回答いただいたのにすみません

Answer (score 2):

Cygwin で `openssh` パッケージをインストールすれば Windows7 で SSH が使えますよ。

Comment: cygwin はかなり古い方法でいまは msys とか mingw がいいっていう記事が多かったんですが cygwin っていうのを使ったほうが楽なんでしょうか

Comment: 比較したことないので何とも言えませんが、Cygwinで上手くいかなかったことはないですね。CygtermとTeraTermが使える点が個人的な決めてになってます。

Answer (score 2):

邪道ですが、[Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/)をインストールすると、gitのついでに sshもインストールされます。

Comment: いれてみました　/c/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/ssh でパスも勝手に通してくれて ssh だけで動いたんですがやはり MSYS 上だと Pseudo-terminal というメッセージが出るのもプライベートキーを指定するとパーミッションあきすぎといわれるのも変わらないです

Answer (score 1):

特に実行環境に制約は無さそうに思われますが、[sayuriさんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/60968/2808)にあるGit for Windowsを利用する方法では何が問題なんでしょうか？

---

> あきらめて
>   [コマンドプロンプトからSSH接続したい](https://usado.jp/spdsk/2018/06/01/post-3815/)
>
> こちらの方法を試してみて

chicoさんの環境ではこれがpath上に存在しており、諸々の問題はここからきているようです。

- PowerShell/コマンドプロンプトで利用したいのでなければアンインストールします。

  - これがpathに入っているせいで、MSYS上でもこれを利用しようとし、"Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated..." というエラーが出ています。
- これを利用したいのでパーミッションに関するエラーを解消したい、という場合、一番簡単なのはエラーメッセージに表示されている `.ssh` ディレクトリを削除することです。

  - 既に必要な情報を設定しているので削除できない、ということであれば、 [パーミッションを修正するスクリプト](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/OpenSSH-utility-scripts-to-fix-file-permissions)が提供されているようです。

---

> こちらを参考にして MSYS と MinGW をいれて
>
> mingw-get install msys-openssl msys-openssh msys-rsync
>   を行ったところ成功したみたいなんですが
>   どこにインストールされたかわからず

こちらは `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin` にインストールされるようです。

Comment: git についてくる ssh ってことなので　/c/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/ssh　かと思ったんですがぜんぜん違う場所にあったってことなんですね…　回答が悪いわけではなく知識不足でインストール場所を勘違いして回答いただいたのとは別のSSHでうまくいかないと思ってしまった点は申しわけありません。

Answer (score 0):

パソコンを起動するときに USB メモリに 入れた Ubuntu から 起動するようにすると
完全なLinux 環境が簡単に手に入ります。

日本語で解説している人はありますが、本家の説明のページを参考に USB から起動できる Linux 環境を作ってはいかがでしょうか？
パソコンがあれば どこでも Linux を使えるようになると思います。

---

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

#### With a bootable Ubuntu USB stick, you can:

- Install or upgrade Ubuntu
- Test out the Ubuntu desktop experience without touching your PC configuration
- Boot into Ubuntu on a borrowed machine or from an internet cafe
- Use tools installed by default on the USB stick to repair or fix a broken
  configuration

Creating a bootable Ubuntu USB stick from Microsoft Windows is very simple and we're going to cover the process in the next few steps.

Comment: 以前デュアルブート環境は構築したことがあるんですが、Windows 上でもゲームを頻繁に触るので同時起動できる環境にしたいです　申し訳有りません

Comment: Core i5 3320M(2.6GHz) / 4GB の 中古ノートパソコンが １万円 ちょっとで手に入るので、OS なしだと安いので、それに Linux インストールしたらいいのでは？