# VirtualBox で VHD ファイルの指定の仕方

Tags: virtualbox

WIndows 上で Linux コマンド環境を使いたくて
VirtualBox をはじめて使ってみようとしてます

インストールして仮装マシンを１つ作ったところで
Linux をどうやっていれようかという段階です
https://www.ubuntulinux.jp/download/ja-remix-vhd
こちらでディスクのイメージを配布されてるので
これをつかえないかと思ってるところなのですが

デフォルトで仮想マシンを作ったらストレージの S-ATA に vdi 形式のディスクができてしまって特にファイルを選択して作成するような選択肢がありませんでした

新規ディスク作成を選ぶと VHD が選択できるんですが
保存先だけで既存の VHD を使うような項目がありません

どうすれば VHD のディスクイメージを使って仮想マシンを起動できるのでしょうか

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 追記

ハードディスク追加　⇒　既存のディスク

を選択するとこういう画面になって vdl しか選択できず
ファイルの選択画面になりません
右下のボタンもおしてみても何もおこりません

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 追記

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

同じフォルダ内においてみたんですがそれでも選択肢に出てきません

#### 追記

VirtualBox バージョン 6.0.14 r133895 (Qt5.6.2)
ホストOS Windows 7
ゲストOS ubuntu 14.04

Comment: 別の仮想マシンを作り直して目的のvhdファイルを指定してもらうのも一つの方法かと思いますが、いかがでしょうか。

Comment: 最初も１度も vhd 選べるような項目がなかった気がするんですがもう１度試してみます！

Comment: 念のため、VirtualBoxのバージョンや、Windowsの種類 (32bit or 64bit) 等も記載してみてください。

Comment: 追記しました。新規作成でも「すでにある仮想ハードディスクファイルを追加する」を選択すると２番めの画像になって vdi だけが表示されます

Comment: 質問の編集時、入力欄の上にあるツールバーから画像を貼り付ける事ができるのでこちらを試してください (外部サイトだと将来的に削除された場合に、質問内容が把握できなくなってしまう可能性があるため)。

Comment: 使用しようとしているVHDは既にサポートが終了しており、使用にはリスクが伴います(言わばWindows XPを使うようなものです)。このUbuntuを使わなければならない理由はありますか？他のUbuntuイメージやより最近のバージョンのUbuntuでも構わないと言うことはありますか？

Comment: >使用しようとしているVHDは既にサポートが終了しており　そうなのですね。トップのダウンロードにあったので最新かと思ってました。それが古いとなるとHDDイメージはあきらめてインストールイメージからインストールするしかないんですね。おとなしくインストールイメージからインストールしてみます

Comment: 日本語Remix に拘らなければ、構築済みのVDIイメージを配布しているサイトもあるので参考までに。 - https://www.osboxes.org/ubuntu/

Comment: [前の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/60965/)と合わせると最終的な目標は「自分のPCにLinuxコマンドが使える環境を作る」事だと思われます。今の方法にこだわりは無く、また、Ubuntuにもこだわりは無く、とにかくほとんどのLinuxコマンドがだいたい使えるようになればいいということでいいでしょうか？

Comment: 結局インストールイメージからインストールして VirtualBox 上に Linux 環境ひととおりできました。ただ少しエディタ上で文字うつとラグがあるのでネイティブ環境に作れたほうが理想でしたがしばらく使ってみます

Comment: >Ubuntuにもこだわりは無く、とにかくほとんどのLinuxコマンドがだいたい使えるようになればいい　はい、学校の課題やるには java-sdk と gcc と python(pyenv) と zsh, sublime エディタが使えればというところです

Answer (score 0, accepted):

仮想マシンの設定画面でストレージデバイスの「コントローラ: SATA」の列にある
右側のアイコン (HDDに＋) をクリックして、「既存のディスクを選択」からvhdファイルを指定してください。

(新規作成時の)不要なディスクは、右クリックから「割当を除去」を選択します。

**ストレージデバイスの設定画面** (VirtualBox 5.2.34)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: うまくいかなかったので追記しました