# OpenSSHで公開鍵認証ができない。

Tags: openssh

Windows Server 2012R2にOpenSSHサーバをインストールしました。
しかし、公開鍵認証がうまくいかず、毎回パスワードを聞かれてしまいます。
なお、クライアントはWindows 10です。

いろんなサイトを見て、何度も試しましたがうまくいきません。
公開鍵・秘密鍵を何度も作り直しましたが・・・どういった設定が必要なのか
教えていただけますでしょうか？

1) 通常のSSHアクセスは問題なくできる。
下記を実行して、パスワードを入力するとSSH画面に切り替わる。

```
$ssh administrator@server
```

2) サーバ側のssh-agentサービス、sshdサービスは両方とも稼働している。
3) クライアント側のssh-agentサービスも稼働している。
4) クライアント側で下記のコマンドを実行し、公開鍵と秘密鍵を作成。

```
$ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

5) サーバ側はadministratorなので、クライアントで作った公開鍵を「C:\ProgramData\ssh」フォルダに「administrators_authorized_keys」にリネームして保存。

6) クライアント側は下記のコマンドを実行して、秘密鍵を登録。

```
$eval `ssh-agent`
$ssh-add id_rsa
```

7) サーバ側を再起動

8) サーバにsshでアクセス
⇒　やはりパスワードを聞いてくる。

[image: サーバアクセス]

以下 `ssh -v` を実行した結果になります。
サーバは{server}、ユーザーは{user}としております。

```
 $ ssh -v administrator@{server}
OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to {server} [10.123.12.212] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to {server}:22 as 'administrator'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:zFLJ6u5M7eGbURhLEIRruUZHQcIFuBx0F6nDLBacz5k
debug1: Host '{server}' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:lWkAW3gm3OZM5dcG9KQRxUPRQ+YPqq8BKObjsPeTe9k
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:lWkAW3gm3OZM5dcG9KQRxUPRQ+YPqq8BKObjsPeTe9k
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/{user}/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
administrator@{server}'s password:
```

2020.5.8追記
ladle様に教えていただいた記事を参考に、公開鍵のパーミッションを設定したところうまくいきました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: sshdのログは確認しましたか？

Comment: もう1つ問題があり、ログファイルが生成されません。C:\ProgramData\ssh\logsフォルダになると思うのですが。

Comment: ロギングに関しては、[こちらの記事](https://serverfault.com/a/957397)が参考になるかと思います。

Comment: ssh -v administrator@server を実行してログインした時の出力はどうなりますか?

Comment: ssh -vの実行結果について下記に回答させていただきました。

Comment: パスワード認証のプロンプトまでではなく、パスワードを入力してログインまで行ってください。

Comment: ladle様に教えていただいた記事を参考に、公開鍵のパーミッションを設定したところうまくいきました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 次の投稿はあなたの質問の回答になりますか？ [Windows 7 から ssh が使いたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/60965/windows-7-%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89-ssh-%e3%81%8c%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%84%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

マイクロソフト社移植版OpenSSH(Win32-OpenSSH)を利用しているのであれば(他の移植版とは異なり)ファイルパーミッションを厳密に見ており、設定がおかしいと期待通り動作しない場合が多々あります。

次のリンク先に説明がありますが、修正用のスクリプトが同梱されています。

- https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/OpenSSH-utility-scripts-to-fix-file-permissions

  > Improper file permissions will likely result in a broken configuration (OpenSSH fails to work). You may use the following scripts (provided in release payload) to help evaluate and fix any permission related issues.